# Storing a substring of one line in a text file to a separate text file

Tags: batch-file

I have a file which contains 5 lines :

```
Resolving portal... ip_address
Connecting to portal|ip_address|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Found
Location: http://portal1.com/portal [following]
Connecting to portal1.com|ip_address|:80... connected.
```

How can I use a batch script to save the string `http://portal1.com/` (on line 4) to a text file called url.txt?

Comment: Where would be that batch file running on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL enabledelayedexpansion
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%a IN (yourtextfile.txt) DO (
    SET line=%%a
    IF "!line:~0,10!"=="Location: " SET location=%%a
)
FOR /F "tokens=2 delims=/" %%l IN ("%location%") DO (
    ECHO http://%%l/ > url.txt
)
```

Answer (score 1):

This does what you want:

```
for /f "tokens=2 delims=/" %%a in ('findstr /L "Location:" lines.txt') do echo http://%%a/ > url.txt
```

Note you will have to replace `lines.txt` with the correct name for you text file.